# Summarize values every 3 days based on date column

Tags: r

Following is the `dput()` output of DT. I would like to sum the values every 3 days, starting from the MIN of DATE, group by ID.

```
structure(list(ID = c("pqr", "abc", "ort", "kkg", "ssc", "ccv", 
"xyz", "xyz", "xyz"), DATE = c("2022-06-07", "2022-06-24", "2022-06-02", 
"2022-06-01", "2022-06-16", "2022-06-07", "2022-06-11", "2022-06-13", "2022-06-27"
), READING_IN = c(150, 2800, 600, 500, 1395.94, 500, 800, 179, 200
), READING_OUT = c(150, 2800, 600, 500, 1400, 501.4, 371.34, 
556.47, 462.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Following is an unsuccessful attempt.

```
DT$DATE = as.Date(DT$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
DT1 = DT %>%
  group_by(ID, group = cut(as.Date(DT$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), '3 days')) %>%
  summarise(date_range = paste(min(DATE), min(DATE) + 2, sep = ' to '), 
            sum_in =  sum(READING_IN),
            sum_out = sum(READING_OUT), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(-group)
```

Result:

```
structure(list(ID = c("abc", "ccv", "kkg", "ort", "pqr", "ssc", 
"xyz", "xyz", "xyz"), date_range = c("2022-06-24-2022-06-26", 
"2022-06-07-2022-06-09", "2022-06-01-2022-06-03", "2022-06-02-2022-06-04", 
"2022-06-07-2022-06-09", "2022-06-16-2022-06-18", "2022-06-11-2022-06-13", 
"2022-06-13-2022-06-15", "2022-06-27-2022-06-29"), sum_in = c(2800, 
500, 500, 600, 150, 1395.94, 800, 179, 200), sum_out = c(2800, 
501.4, 500, 600, 150, 1400, 371.34, 556.47, 462.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Desired Output for ID = xyz:

| ID | DATE | READING_IN | READING_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 2022-06-11 to 2022-06-13 | 979 | 927.81 |
| xyz | 2022-06-27 to 2022-06-29 | 200 | 462.75 |

I understand the issue here is the entry on 2022-06-13, an entry which should be aggregated in 2022-06-11 + 2 window. Is there any way to sum the values every 3 days aligned to desired output format?

Comment: Please include a sample from your actual dataset as `dput()` output (i.e. `dput(head(DT))` ). When I'm re-constructing it from the included table and have column types as `chr Date num num` , code snippet you provided does return desired output.

Comment: @margusl , Apologies for attending the comment late. You're right about the finding. However, the sample produced here is a part of large DF. Following is the `dput()` output of DF. 
`structure(list(ID = c("PQR","ABC", "MOR", "ILT", "BBT","PLB"), DATE = structure(c(19150, 
19167, 19145, 19144, 19159, 19150), class = "Date"), READING_IN = c(150, 
2800, 600, 500, 1395.94, 500), READING_OUT = c(150, 2800, 600, 
500, 1400, 501.4)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Also, the format of DATE column is not recognized as date format in `dput()` output. Upon changing them using `format(DT$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")`, the code fails to execute as the column is no more recognized as date format.

Comment: All the IDs in provided dataset are unique while in tables in question there's just one distinct value. Note that you still can (and should!) edit your question to include any relevant updates.

Comment: Edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were tricked by some `group_by()` [details](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html#:%7E:text=for%20more%20details.-,...,nest_by().%20In%20ungroup()%2C%20variables%20to%20remove%20from%20the%20grouping.,-.add):

> Computations are always done on the ungrouped data frame. To perform computations on the grouped data, you need to use a separate `mutate()` step before the `group_by()`.

With extra `mutate()` + `group_by()` step it seems to behave like described:

```r
library(tibble)  
library(dplyr)
  DT %>%
    mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(date_group = cut(DATE, '3 days')) %>% 
    group_by(ID, date_group) %>%
    summarise(date_range = paste(min(DATE), min(DATE) + 2, sep = ' to '), 
              sum_in =  num(sum(READING_IN), digits = 2),
              sum_out = num(sum(READING_OUT),digits = 2), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    select(-date_group)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   ID    date_range                  sum_in   sum_out
#>   <chr> <chr>                    <num:.2!> <num:.2!>
#> 1 abc   2022-06-24 to 2022-06-26   2800.00   2800.00
#> 2 ccv   2022-06-07 to 2022-06-09    500.00    501.40
#> 3 kkg   2022-06-01 to 2022-06-03    500.00    500.00
#> 4 ort   2022-06-02 to 2022-06-04    600.00    600.00
#> 5 pqr   2022-06-07 to 2022-06-09    150.00    150.00
#> 6 ssc   2022-06-16 to 2022-06-18   1395.94   1400.00
#> 7 xyz   2022-06-11 to 2022-06-13    979.00    927.81
#> 8 xyz   2022-06-27 to 2022-06-29    200.00    462.75
```

Input:

```r
DT <- structure(list(
  ID = c(
    "pqr", "abc", "ort", "kkg", "ssc", "ccv", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz"
  ),
  DATE = c(
    "2022-06-07", "2022-06-24", "2022-06-02", "2022-06-01", "2022-06-16",
    "2022-06-07", "2022-06-11", "2022-06-13", "2022-06-27"
  ),
  READING_IN = c(150, 2800, 600, 500, 1395.94, 500, 800, 179, 200),
  READING_OUT = c(150, 2800, 600, 500, 1400, 501.4, 371.34, 556.47, 462.75)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>